# Android 9 app pinning not working

Tags: 9.0-pie

My LG V35 was recently upgraded to Android 9 and after the upgrade app pinning stopped working. I can pin an app but it gets unpinned by the OS and removed from the list of my recent apps. This was never a problem with Android 8 before the update. Any app I pinned before the upgrade stayed permanently pinned even after restarting.

I tried adding apps I want to stay pinned to the list of power saving exclusions but that did not help.

Any ideas how to fix this or is this "normal" OS behavior with Pie?

Edit: This question is **not** about *screen pinning*, it **is** about *app pinning* (the little pin shown on the app title bar when app list is open).

Comment: I am also running android 9 on my moto x4. Tested this, set screen pin from settings. Tapping navigation buttons remains to same screen. Locked phone, and while unlock device shows pinned screen as lock screen. But, on reboot, you'll lose pinned screen.

Comment: @RahulGopi Thanks for the comment but the question was not about screen pinning, it was about app pinning (the little pin shown on the app itself when app list is open).